# Ordering Submenu Pages in WP 3.1

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, upgrade, admin-menu, customization

I just recently upgraded to WordPress 3.1 a few moments ago. However, I noticed that when you have Post Types show up under a *main* menu page, it overrides the link fo th menu link.

[image]

Here's my `register_post_type` arguments for "Visitor" post type.

```
    $v_args = array(
        'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'Visitors',
                'singular_name' => 'Visitor',
                'add_new_item' => 'Register New Visitor', // TODO: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => 'argus',
        //'show_in_menu' => false,
        'hiearchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( '' ),
        'capabilities' => $visitor_caps,
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array ( &$this, '_wp_visitor_meta_box_cb' ),
    );

    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
    register_post_type( $post_type, $v_args );
```

Here is the call to `add_menu_page` that adds the link to the admin menu.

```
public function _wp_admin_menu( )
{
    add_menu_page( 'Argus', 'Argus Admin', 'argus', 'argus', array( &$this, '_wp_argus_main_panel' ), '', -1 );
    add_submenu_page( 'argus', 'Argus Administration', 'Main Menu', 'argus', 'argus', array( &$this, '_wp_argus_main_panel' ) );        
    // save having to register 'admin_menu' action across every sub-plugin
    // There is no 'admin_menu' function/method in any class stored in $classes
    foreach( self::$classes as $class => $obj )
    {
        if ( method_exists( $obj, 'admin_menu' ) )
        {
            $obj->admin_menu();
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note:** The call to `add_submenu_page` was added after the fact and doesn't change the behavior or output one bit. I added this to re-add the default link that 3.0.4 added by default under the link header generated by `add_menu_page`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments):

> Note: When using 'some string' to show
>   as a submenu of a menu page created by
>   a plugin, this item will become the
>   first submenu item, and replace the
>   location of the top level link. If
>   this isn't desired, the plugin that
>   creates the menu page needs to set the
>   add_action priority for admin_menu to
>   9 or lower.

So on you `add_action('admin_menu',array($this,'_wp_admin_menu'));` set priority to 9 or lower like so:

```
add_action('admin_menu',array($this,'_wp_admin_menu'),2);
```

and you should be set.